# Can' read images uploaded to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js, aws-sdk

I'm uploading images to `AWS S3` as Buffer (as it's required by `aws-sdk`), but then this image just can't be read as a normal image - it looks in the browser just like a small white square. What I'm missing here?

On Next.js API

```js
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: "key",
  secretAccessKey: "key",
});

const params = {
  Bucket: "bucket",
  Key: `${Date.now().toString()}.jpg`,
  Body: Buffer.from(req.body),
  ContentType: "image/png",
};

s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data}`);
});
```

Client side:

```js
const handleImageUpload = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { files } = e.target;
    const formData = new FormData();
    if (files && files[0]) {
      formData.append("image", files[0]);
      fetch("/api/upload.image", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
      });
    }
  };
```

Here is an example of the answer from server:

```js
    <ref *2> ManagedUpload {
      _events: {},
      body: <Buffer 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 57 65 62 4b 69 74 46 6f 72 6d 42 6f 75 6e 64 61 72 79 51 41 62 63 59 76 32 45 4e 6c 34 77 77 79 70 57 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d ... 93798 more bytes>,
      sliceFn: [Function: slice],
      callback: [Function (anonymous)],
      parts: {},
      completeInfo: [],
      fillQueue: [Function: fillBuffer],
      partSize: 5242880,
      service: Service {
        config: Config {
          credentials: [Credentials],
          credentialProvider: [CredentialProviderChain],
          region: 'us-east-1',
          logger: null,
          apiVersions: {},
          apiVersion: null,
          endpoint: 's3.amazonaws.com',
          httpOptions: [Object],
          maxRetries: undefined,
          maxRedirects: 10,
          paramValidation: true,
          sslEnabled: true,
          s3ForcePathStyle: false,
          s3BucketEndpoint: false,
          s3DisableBodySigning: true,
          s3UsEast1RegionalEndpoint: undefined,
          s3UseArnRegion: undefined,
          computeChecksums: true,
          convertResponseTypes: true,
          correctClockSkew: false,
          customUserAgent: null,
          dynamoDbCrc32: true,
          systemClockOffset: 0,
          signatureVersion: 'v4',
          signatureCache: true,
          retryDelayOptions: {},
          useAccelerateEndpoint: false,
          clientSideMonitoring: false,
          endpointDiscoveryEnabled: undefined,
          endpointCacheSize: 1000,
          hostPrefixEnabled: true,
          stsRegionalEndpoints: 'legacy',
          accessKeyId: 'xxx',
          secretAccessKey: 'xxx',
          params: [Object]
        },
        isGlobalEndpoint: false,
        endpoint: Endpoint {
          protocol: 'https:',
          host: 's3.amazonaws.com',
          port: 443,
          hostname: 's3.amazonaws.com',
          pathname: '/',
          path: '/',
          href: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/'
        },
        _events: { apiCallAttempt: [Array], apiCall: [Array] },
        MONITOR_EVENTS_BUBBLE: [Function: EVENTS_BUBBLE],
        CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE: [Function: CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE],
        _clientId: 2
      },
      totalBytes: 93848,
      failed: false,
      partPos: 5242880,
      isDoneChunking: true,
      numParts: 1,
      totalPartNumbers: 1,
      singlePart: <ref *1> Request {
        domain: null,
        service: Service {
          config: [Config],
          isGlobalEndpoint: false,
          endpoint: [Endpoint],
          _events: [Object],
          MONITOR_EVENTS_BUBBLE: [Function: EVENTS_BUBBLE],
          CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE: [Function: CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE],
          _clientId: 2
        },
        operation: 'putObject',
        params: {
          Body: <Buffer 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 57 65 62 4b 69 74 46 6f 72 6d 42 6f 75 6e 64 61 72 79 51 41 62 63 59 76 32 45 4e 6c 34 77 77 79 70 57 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d ... 93798 more bytes>,
          Bucket: 'codest-images',
          Key: '1613572736403.jpg',
          ContentType: 'image/png',
          ACL: 'public-read'
        },
        httpRequest: HttpRequest {
          method: 'PUT',
          path: '/1613572736403.jpg',
          headers: [Object],
          body: <Buffer 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 57 65 62 4b 69 74 46 6f 72 6d 42 6f 75 6e 64 61 72 79 51 41 62 63 59 76 32 45 4e 6c 34 77 77 79 70 57 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d ... 93798 more bytes>,
          endpoint: [Object],
          region: 'us-east-1',
          _userAgent: 'aws-sdk-nodejs/2.840.0 darwin/v14.15.4 callback',
          virtualHostedBucket: 'codest-images',
          stream: [ClientRequest]
        },
        startTime: 2021-02-17T14:38:56.406Z,
        response: Response {
          request: [Circular *1],
          data: null,
          error: null,
          retryCount: 0,
          redirectCount: 0,
          httpResponse: [HttpResponse],
          maxRetries: 3,
          maxRedirects: 10
        },
        _asm: AcceptorStateMachine { currentState: 'send', states: [Object] },
        _haltHandlersOnError: false,
        _events: {
          validate: [Array],
          afterBuild: [Array],
          restart: [Array],
          sign: [Array],
          validateResponse: [Array],
          send: [Array],
          httpHeaders: [Array],
          httpData: [Array],
          httpDone: [Array],
          retry: [Array],
          afterRetry: [Array],
          build: [Array],
          extractData: [Array],
          extractError: [Array],
          httpError: [Array],
          beforePresign: [Array],
          success: [Array],
          complete: [Array],
          httpUploadProgress: [Array]
        },
        emit: [Function: emit],
        API_CALL_ATTEMPT: [Function: API_CALL_ATTEMPT],
        API_CALL_ATTEMPT_RETRY: [Function: API_CALL_ATTEMPT_RETRY],
        API_CALL: [Function: API_CALL],
        _managedUpload: [Circular *2],
        signedAt: 2021-02-17T14:38:56.415Z
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you download images from S3 manually, they are OK?

Comment: have you tried to upload in S3 using a signed url ?

Comment: s3.upload is an async function (with callback) are you sure that the API route waits properly until the upload is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it was solved this way.

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
import fs from "fs";
import formidable, { File as FFile } from "formidable";

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
): Promise<void> {
  try {
    const s3 = new AWS.S3({
      accessKeyId: "xxx",
      secretAccessKey: "xxx",
    });

    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.uploadDir = "./";
    form.keepExtensions = true;
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      fs.readFile((files.image as FFile).path, (_, image) => {
        const params = {
          Bucket: "codest-images",
          Key: (files.image as FFile).name,
          Body: image,
          ContentType: (files.image as FFile).type,
          ContentSize: (files.image as FFile).size,
          ACL: "public-read",
        };
        s3.upload(
          params,
          (error: Error, data: AWS.S3.ManagedUpload.SendData) => {
            if (error) {
              res.status(400).json(error.message);
              res.end();
            } else {
              res.status(200).json(data.Location);
            }
          }
        );
      });
    });
  } catch (ex) {
    res.status(400).json({ err: ex });
    res.end();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the image content from `req.body` which is incorrect. If you print `req.body` on console, you will see something like this -

```
------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; 
filename="image.jpeg"
Content-Type: application/json
your file content buffer
```

You can either parse this to get the buffer content. Or I prefer to use a library like `multer` to read files from FormData. Following is your NextJS code using multer.

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
var multer = require("multer");
var upload = multer();

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false, // This is important. Else multer won't be parsing your form data
  },
};

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  upload.single("image")(req, {}, (err) => { // 'image' is the element name in the form
    console.log(req.file); // you will see file metadata and the buffer here
    const params = {
      Bucket: "bucket",
      Key: `${Date.now().toString()}.jpg`,
      Body: req.file.buffer,
      ContentType: "image/jpeg",
    };
    s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: "Error while uploading" });
      } else {
        console.log(`File uploaded successfully`, data);
        res.status(200).send({ message: "File uploaded succesfully" });
      }
    });
  });
}
```